# Jar file - runs faster?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I exported a java application as a jar file using eclipse. The application runs has a recursive algorithm which runs for around 4 hours. But when I run as a jar file, it takes only an hour. Do jar files usually run faster?

Comment: Compared to running in Eclipse?

Comment: Jar is just packaged classes files... there is not reason for it to run faster. But I am no JVM guru.

Comment: Run faster in comparison to Eclipse's running, right?

Comment: yes. does it run faster compared to running in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that under Eclipse it is in sort of a debugger environment so that it will actually slow down your code execution due to the debugger overhead. Since running in a JAR has no debugger overhead from Eclipse, then it will likely be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `JAR` files are archive files which include a Java-specific manifest file.

They are built on the `ZIP` format and typically have a .jar file extension.

Therefore, it is surely nothing do with performance.

I assume either you are in a `debug` environment which slows code execution or you have set of `plug-ins` installed in your IDE.

Try to remove `plug-ins` not used and check performance.